# ClassName Snippet for vscode and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make VScode to autocomplete/make a snippet of className so when i choose is it it will complete to className={``} (instead of current situation when it just complete to "className" ) ?
Thanks

Comment: Please show more code to show what you are selecting in what context and the desired result.  It needs to be more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [TabNine](https://www.tabnine.com/) or [VSCode IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) and see if that helps, but it is hard for an IDE to assume 100% what you want to do, I am just giving examples of extensions that might help more.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a snippet and you can set className by reading your fileName.

you can refer Documentation.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode, click `CTRL + SHIFT + P` to open the command window. Type 'Configure user snippets' and select the first file. It will open a file containing your user defined snippets. Inside the topmost curly brackets, right before the closing bracket, insert a comma then the following snippet:

```
    "ClassName with formated string": {
    "prefix": "cla",
    "body": [
        "className = {`",
        "   ${1:}",
        "`}"
    ],
    "description": "ClassName with formated string"
}
```

So, the file will look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSQji.png)

To use the snippet, type cla, which should bring it as an option in your autocomplete menu